# How to upgrade Ajax Control Toolkit to the latest version only to a particular solution

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2012

I am planning to upgrade Ajax Control Toolkit (ACT) from version 4.x to the latest 15.x. I have several Visual Studio solutions running on the same computer, and I want to upgrade only for some solutions and keep the others running the existing older versions. Initially I thought of using the DevExpress's installer for the latest ACT at https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/618129 . But the problem is that it is an .exe installer and per the documentation it will install on all the Visual Studio solutions/projects. I saw another option of using nuget's package manager at https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/ using the command PM> install-package AjaxControlToolKit. I am not sure whether this will also install on all projects or only the project opened on which I ran the command. If there is a better safe way of upgrading the ACT, I would like to know also, such as copy/paste/replace the older dll with newer one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the nuget's method given in the second link mentioned above. It specifically adds new dll to the selected solution/project only.

Answer (score 0):

In the past years the AjaxControlToolkit has been adopted by DevExpress, by the grace of Microsoft itself. On the now [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit) for the AjaxControlToolkit there is a handy guide in their documentation that walks you through [upgrading from 7.x or lower to v18+](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below).

In a nutshell it covers the following main changes:

1. Installing the latest version (tip: use NuGet for only a particular solution)
2. Replace ToolkitScriptManager with ScriptManager
3. Clean up Web.config
4. Use Microsoft.Web.Optimization for bundling and minification
5. Html Editor (namespace changes)

Its basically a one pager and it dit help me in covering the main pain points of upgrading such a major change.

Please note that in terms of versioning, there aren't that many major bumps: from v8 it bumps directly to v15 and up to v19 as of 2019. Every major version since 2015 is prefixed with the year or release as major version. And it stopped in 2020 with v20.1.0. See the [version history at NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/).